# PhpStorm - how to highlight code block via keyboard?

Tags: html, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

Using PhpStorm, how to highlight code block without pressing <kbd>Shift + Down</kbd>?

For example

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Label</label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input type="checkbox">Install</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

If Text-cursor is on the `<div class="col-sm-7">` then I like highlight that block:

```
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input type="checkbox">Install</label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried the extend selection option? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.3/selecting-text-in-the-editor.html#d616791e170

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> (Windows default) or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> (OS X) to select increasingly expansive scopes. E.g. if the cursor is here at "col-sm":

```
<div class="col-sm|-7">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox">Install</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> once selects all of `col-sm-7`, pressing it again selects the surrounding quotes, pressing it again the entire attribute, then the entire tag, and finally the tag including its content and closing tag. This works for scopes in all supported languages, not just HTML.